# What are the differences between running a web app under the VS Dev Server and under IIS?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, iis-7, visual-studio-debugging

I have a huge, complex solution here, and if try running it for debugging under the Viusual  Studio Development Server, I get an error "Could not load file or assembly 'soss_svcdotnet' Incorrect file format."  When I run the app under IIS, I don't get the error.

This seems to be a 32 vs 64 -bit issue, but I'm sure there are more differences.  So, I am prompted to ask, what are these differences?

Comment: Are you running the instance of IIS on your dev system as well? Could it be that soss_svcdotnet isn't on your system/in the project/isn't registered in your GAC?

Comment: @Lazarus, the assembly is in the project.  I just copied it in again minutes ago to be sure.  This is the essence of my problem right now.  BTW, I am running IIS on my dev box, the virtual folder is set to my source folder where my dev code resides.

Comment: I am clutching at straws here as I've no way to reproduce this but are there any additional errors logged by the StateServer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VS Dev Server runs the website under your user account, with all of the permissions associated with that (and the fact that it's an interactive user on the computer), whereas IIS will typically run the site under a dedicated ASP.Net account, with limited permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following in regards to the error message you are getting.
[Link](http://weblogs.asp.net/hosamkamel/archive/2009/10/11/resolved-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-xxxxx-or-one-of-its-dependencies-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format.aspx)

It could be that the soss assembly you are referencing is built for a 32bit processor and its now blowing up when you try to run it under 64.  You may need to either recompile or download the 64bit version if its an external lib.